# push notifications set large icon when sending from server

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm sending push notifications from server with PHP like so:

```
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'xxx');

 $msg = array(
            'body'  => $body,
            'title' => $title,
            'android_channel_id' => $type
            );

$fields = array(
            'to' => $token,
            'notification'  => $msg
            );


$headers = array
            (
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
echo $result;
curl_close( $ch );
```

But I don't know how to set a large icon

This are the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

It only says how to set the small icon but I want to set a large one on the right side!

There are tutorials and also answers on stackoverflow which are showing how to do this when you send a message to the device you are using currently like so:

```
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lotti);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_one)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(getString(R.string.long_dummy_text))
                    .setBigContentTitle("Big Content Title")
                    .setSummaryText("Summary Text"))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setColor(Color.BLUE)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Toast", actionIntent)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

But WHO THE HELL NEED IT THAT WAY??? 99% of apps receive push notifications which are sent from the server. What's the point of sending a notification from the app/device to the same app/device you are using right now???????

I hope I explained the problem understandable. Please help